# Can Kafka reassign partition to another consumer based solely on traffic?

Tags: apache-kafka, load-balancing, kafka-consumer-api

I'm investigating the possibility to use Kafka in my project as a message broker with a strong message processing order guarantees.

I learned that in Kafka topic is split into partitions, where each partition will have exactly one consumer assigned (assuming there is a single consumer group). This is good for keeping ordering. Rebalancing is the process of reassigning partitions to consumers and it is triggered when number of partitions or number of consumers is changed (failures, new workers added).

Is there possibility to utilize that rebalancing on-the-fly without changing number of consumers?

Let say we have a following scenario:

```
                P1 -- C1

heavytraffic -> P2 -- C2
heavytraffic -> P3 --/
```

So consumer C1 is handling only P1 partition and C2 has two assigned: P2,P3.
Let's say there is a big traffic on P2,P3 but P1 is idle.

```
                P1 -- C1
heavytraffic -> P2 --/
 
heavytraffic -> P3 -- C2
```

Is there any way for Kafka to reassign for example P2 to C1 to increase the utilization of consumers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although each partition will have exactly one consumer, one consumer can be assigned to multiple partitions. In order to get the best performance you would therefore match the number of partitions with the number of consumers within a ConsumerGroup that is subscribed to the topic.

The rebalancing is based on the consumer rebalance strategies (see configuration below) and is not done based on the traffic or workload. As soon as the rebalance is done, the assignments are fixed until another rebalance is happening.

Usually, it is best to avoid any rebalances as during that time all consumers of the ConsumerGroup are paused and will not poll any data. Therefore, I would not use the rebalancing to balance your workload. If the traffic is so different on various partitions I would rather consider to split some partitions into another topic or split the partitions into more partitions. If you have more partitions you can make use of more consumers.

> [partition.assignment.strategy](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#partition.assignment.strategy): A list of class names or class types, ordered by preference, of supported partition assignment strategies that the client will use to distribute partition ownership amongst consumer instances when group management is used. In addition to the default class specified below, you can use the org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RoundRobinAssignorclass for round robin assignments of partitions to consumers. Implementing the org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerPartitionAssignor interface allows you to plug in a custom assignment strategy.

Comment: I am trying to achieve something like a "message group" feature - guarantee ordering at the scope of each message groups (~1000 groups) while consume this by a 10-20 workers. Groups may not be well balanced, so it would be preferred not to tie the consumer in a fixed manner, rather make the mappings on an ad-hoc basis.

I found old-fashioned systems to have that feature (Weblogic JMS, Apache Qpid, ActiveMq) but none of the modern ones - Kafka, RabbitMQ.

Comment: Okay, well... answer is the same. :)